# How to logout from facebook from the application in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Please help me with a solution!.I have a iPhone app which uses the new facebook sdk(FBConnect).The app is related to video sharing.I should embed a logout button to sign out the current user from my app.I implemented it by calling `fn{currentAPICall = kAPILogout;[[facebookObject]logout:self]}` from my wrapper class.....tis logout shd call the logout method in facebook.m.The code is executed as expected but it does not logout from my app,again on relaunching my app it is redirected to the previous account.
Any solutions!

Answer (score 0):

In the DidLogout code, remove the NSDefaults that you stored for the session. Just set them to ""